# Random Flip Card HTML JavaScript

Tags: html, image, random, flip

I'm supposed to make a set of cards appear on random orders and it seems like I haven't been able to do so due to the amount of error seen on the console. I'm not confident about writing JavaScript as I'm still in the learning process. There are 38 photo cards and when I refresh the page, the photos are supposed to change their orders.

```
  let card = document.createElement("div");
  let front = document.createElement("div");
  let back = document.createElement("div");
  front.classList.add("card-front");
  back.classList.add("card-back");
  card.appendChild(front);
  card.appendChild(back);
  card.classList.add("card");
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  parent.appendChild(img);

  let cards = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    let num = document.createElement('card-front');
    num.appendChild(i);
    cards.push(num);
    //num.textContent = r;
    //pearent.appendChild(num);
  }

  while(cards.length != 0) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
    let n = cards.splice(r, 1);
    parent.appendChild(n[0]);
    let cont = document.getElementById("CONTAINER");
    parent.appendChild(n[0]);
  }
```

[The HTML looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov3Ro.png)

Comment: From what I see from the picture with your HTML I can see that you use the same ID repeatedly for different elements. You can't do that!

Comment: Please post the code as a text and not as an image.

Comment: My bad! Probably the biggest mistake was to add ID to every elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @54ka already said, your usage of the `id` attribute is wrong. An `id` has to be unique. So it must only occurre once in you whole document. This is why your `document.getElementById()` is not working correctly.

The following example uses a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) together with the [flexbox `order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property) that is randomized by javascript. This means there is no removing and adding of elements. It just sets the order directly to be random. This is a lot cleaner. Also this separates better (in my opinion) between styling, done with css, and "functionality" done by javascript.

```js
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
if(cards !== null){
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    cards.item(i).style.order = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
  }
 }
```

```css
.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 430px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.card{
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00ff000" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffff00" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to stick with adding and removing (**which I do not suggest!**) you can use the following code:

```js
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
if(cards !== null){
  // create a list that contains all indices of the cards
  let card_indices = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    card_indices.push(i);
  }
  
  // randomize the card indices and insert the card
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    // get a random card index
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * card_indices.length);
    // re-add this element to the same parent to the front, adding
    // all elements will shuffle them
    let card = cards.item(card_indices[j]);
    card.parentNode.appendChild(card);
    // mark this index as taken
    card_indices.splice(j, 1);
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00ff000" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">  
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffff00" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The flexbox layout is very helpful + the explanation is very clear. And I fully agree, the code looks much cleaner! Thanks a lot!